# Django oauth toolkit Permission for access_token generated by client_credential

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using Django oauth toolkit with django-restframework for implementing a sets of Apis for a client application. My problem is when i genereting a token with grant client_credentials i get 403 in access on my view (in access token table there is not set a user). How can solve this issue ?

Best 
Luca

Comment: Facing the same issue, have got any solution?